# Angular: Promise http call doesn't wait

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to upload some files using http call. i loop through the files list 
 in `uploadFiles` function and upload each file by calling `filesUpLoader` 
 function. My problem is the function `filesUpLoader` doesn't wait until it's 
 done despite it's Promise and i used `await` keyword.

at below screenshot i am uploading two files and the result as you can see
 the http call doesn't wait.
 Thank you so much

[image]

**This is my code**

```
 this.uploadFiles(files);

 uploadFiles(files:FileList)
 {

 Array.from(files).forEach(  async file => {

 await this.filesUpLoader(file);

 setTimeout(()=>{ console.log("This Delay") }, 4000);
 });

 }

 filesUpLoader(file:File)
 {
  const url = "website.com";
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('MediaFile', file, file.name);
  this.http.post(url, formData).toPromise().then(data=>
      {
        console.log("This HTTP Call");
      },
      error=> 
      {
      console.log(error.error.Message);
      });
}
```

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Can you please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: Try using the function in for loop and it should work, as expected.

Comment: It will wait for the promise, but it won't wait for the `setTimeout`, so `uploadFiles` will return 4 seconds before your `console.log` is printed. If you move that outside of the setTimeout, you'll see a different result

Comment: @user184994. It worked! Thank you :) i just used setTimeout to ensure that the http call will wait or not . Can you please tell me how can something other than setTimeout to test the waiting for any http call. Thank you so much

Comment: What is it you want to test? You should just be able to put `console.log` directly underneath the `await` and it won't print until it's waited

Comment: I want to make any delay in for each function to make sure that the function filesUpLoader will wait until the delay is finished

Comment: Okay, I understand now. You don't want to start the next http call until the previous one has finished. In that case, instead of `.forEach` use `for (file of Array.from(files))` instead. Here is a StackBlitz basic demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isgauf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts